# How to add prices in mongoDB using mongoose, express js and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here I am inserting documents in DB:

```js
await TestMOdel.insertMany([
        {   Model: "Samsung",
            price: 45000,
            OS: "MS DOS",
        },
        {
            Model: "Wipro",
            price: 55000,
            OS: "Ubuntu",
        },
        {
            Model: "Dell",
            price: 80000,
            OS: "Unix",
        },
        {
            Model: "Asus",
            price: 30000,
            OS: "Fedora",
        },

    ]);
```

I am stuck on how to sum of all laptop prices as I'm using Node.js (Express) and Mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `aggregate` query and `group` stage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "totalPrice": {
        "$sum": "$price"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bem_n88mOwh)